# How to get pixel values from all frames of a video?

Tags: java, video, compression, codec, frames

I have a project in my university which asks for the creation of a video codec. The problem is the even though i have studied a lot about video compression , techniques , algorithms etc but i can't find anywhere how to get the pixel values from video frames(because this is the first think to do in order to apply Discrete cosine transform later).

Comment: have you done anything then put it here in your question

Comment: What is your source format? Is it encoded or decoded? What is the color space? is it planar?